# python lambda can't detect packaged modules

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, import, lambda, python-requests

I'm trying to create a lambda function by uploading a zip file with a single .py file at the root and 2 folders which contain the requests lib downloaded via pip.

Running the code local works file. When I zip and upload the code I very often get this error:

`Unable to import module 'main': No module named requests`

Sometimes I do manage to fix this, but its inconsistent and I'm not sure how I'm doing it. I'm using the following command:

in root dir `zip -r upload.zip *`

This is how I'm importing requests:

`import requests`

FYI:
1. I have attempted a number of different import methods using the exact path which have failed so I wonder if thats the problem?
2. Every time this has failed and I've been able to make it work in lambda, its involved a lot of fiddling with the zip command as I thought the problem was I was zipping the contents incorrect and hiding them behind an extra parent folder.

Looking forward to seeing the silly mistake i've been making!

Adding code snippet:

```
import json         ##Built In
import requests     ##Packaged with
import sys          ##Built In

def lambda_function(event, context):

alias = event['alias']
message = event['message']
input_type = event['input_type']

if input_type == "username":
    username = alias
elif input_type == "email":
    username = alias.split('@',1)[0]
elif input_type is None:
    print "input_type 'username' or 'email' required. Closing..."
    sys.exit()

payload = {
            "text": message,
            "channel": "@" + username,
            "icon_emoji": "<an emoji>",
            "username": "<an alias>"
          }

r = requests.post("<slackurl>",json=payload)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got some help outside the stackoverflow loop and this seems to consistently work.

`zip -r upload.zip main.py requests requests-2.9.1.dist-info`